# Perl script to count number of each occurrence in a column

Tags: perl, file-handling

I want to count the amount of times each line occurs in a file

Given a column of info like

```
cat woman and bain
bat man
hat woman
cat man
bat man and friends
fat man
hat woman
+bat man
cat woman and bain
super bat man
bat man
bat man
```

I want to receive something like

```
2 cat woman and bain 
3 bat man
2 hat woman
1 cat man
1 bat man and friends
1 fat man
1 +bat man
1 super bat man
```

I kind of have some unfinished code like

```
open OUTFILE, '>text.txt';
while (<>){
        if( text.txt =~ $_ ){
                #increment the count for this occurence
        }else{
                print OUTFILE $_;
        }
}
```

Comment: I think you should be seeking help to improve your existing code so that it works. It isn't that far off, but you are mixing Python syntax into a Perl program, and the result won't compile. What languages do you know? How would you prefer an answer to be phrased?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ sort file | uniq -c
      1 +bat man
      3 bat man
      1 bat man and friends
      1 cat man
      2 cat woman and bain
      1 fat man
      2 hat woman
      1 super bat man
```

or

```
$ perl -e'
   ++$h{$_} while <>;
   printf "%7d %s", $h{$_}, $_ for sort keys(%h);
' file
      1 +bat man
      3 bat man
      1 bat man and friends
      1 cat man
      2 cat woman and bain
      1 fat man
      2 hat woman
      1 super bat man
```

Replace `sort` with `sort { $h{$b} <=> $h{$a} || $a cmp $b }` to sort the output be descending count.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
open INFILE, "<", "input.txt";
open OUTFILE, "+>", "output.txt";
my %hash;
foreach my $line (<INFILE>){
    chomp $line; # Remove trailing newline
    $hash{$line}++;
}

while (my($key,$val) = each %hash) {
    print OUTFILE "$val - $key"
}
```